# Database set up and management

Tags: sql, database, encryption

I am currently in the  process of setting up the data infrastructure for a web portal. I was hoping to get some best practices and advice in setting up and managing my databases and database structure. I will be looking at uploading a large amount of data in excess of potentially 5000 records to begin with and expanding beyond this soon after.

How should I ensure speed, integrity, scalability and security for my databases? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 5000 record meas per second or per day

Comment: 5000 records would be over the period of about a month

Comment: in that scenario you can take any database this is not a huge no ..  use mysql or mssql

Comment: Postgres is a perfect choice for any size (much better then MySQL). And 5000 rows per month is absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks so much, what about implementing the best protocols for data integrity, speed and security?